# How to make input field editable that has a value in reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, input

I'm new to Reactjs and I'm having difficulty in making the input field that has a assign value. Please guys help me.

My js file.

```
       <div className="col-sm-9">
        <input className={this.state.editable ? "edit-profile" : "disable-profile disable"}
        ref="fullName"
        onChange={this._handleInputChange.bind(null, "fullName")}
                        value={user.fullName}/>
```

My button

```
<button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.edit}>
    {this.state.editDone ? "Done" : "Edit Profile"}</button>

edit = () => {
    if (!this.state.editDone) {
        this.setState({ editable: true, editDone: true});
    } else {
        this.setState({ editable: false, editDone: false});
    }
}
```

css file

```
.edit-profile {
outline: 0;
color: #000000;
border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
border-color: #A9A9A9;
width: 30%;
background-color: transparent;
padding-left: 20px;
font-size: 12px;
margin-bottom: 20px;}
```

what I'm suppose to do ?

Comment: value={user.fullName}, is user here props or state?

Comment: it's a props bro

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are handling the value with a `ref`, then use `defaultValue` instead of `value`.

`defaultValue` prop on `input` allows for your *uncontrolled* component to have the initial value set.

`value` requires you to set the value on every render.

So simply change to this:

```
<input className={this.state.editable ? "edit-profile" : "disable-profile disable"}
        ref="fullName"
        onChange={this._handleInputChange.bind(null, "fullName")}
        defaultValue={user.fullName}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value of the button needs to be updated from more places than the input field, you can use the input as a "[controlled component](https://www.altogic.com/blog/difference-between-controlled-and-uncontrolled-component#:%7E:text=In%20React%2C%20controlled%20components%20refer,manage%20their%20own%20state%20internally)". To do that, you can create a "[state variable](https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory)":

```
const [editableValue, setEditableValue] = useState(value)
```

So you can edit your input value from any other place using the "setEditableValue" function. The input will have these parameters:

```
<input value={editableValue} onChange={(e) => setEditableValue(e.target.value)} />
```

The value is modified each time you use the "setEditableValue" function, and that function will be executed each time you write something on the input.